# Android with Groovy - where to place activity.java files that use Groovy classes

Tags: java, android, groovy

In android i have a mainActivity class that is located in the standard java src folder.  I'd like this mainActivity class to access a Groovy class i have created.  The groovy class is in the groovy folder i created under main.  Now inorder for my mainActivity to utilize any groovy class i have to make sure its in the same package.  Now here is my issue, after i move the mainActivity.java file to the groovy folder under main the project cant find the launcher program anymore.  I check the manifest and i guessing it could be the wrong path.  Can anyone tell me where i can place the android activities such that both the manifest and groovy stuff can i see them ?

[image]

and here is my manifest if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to find the issue. the folder i made called groovy is not a package. i have to create a package right under it and in there i can place both groovy and java files.  here is a photo of my directory structure afterwards which compiles fine:

[image]